# How does unique_ptr support both "dot" and "arrow" invocation, and undefined methods?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

As far as I know, in C++ any method invocation on any object has to be pre-defined in its class definition. Therefore, it gets interesting when I look at `std::unique_ptr`.

It seems that `unique_ptr` supports both "dot" (e.g. `reset()`) and "arrow" operations. However, "dot" is for pointers while "arrow" is for objects/references (we can do `ptr->MethodThatTheEncapsulatedClassSupports()`). So how can `unique_ptr` be both a pointer and an object?

The second interesting part is, that the class passed to `unique_ptr` can be arbitrary. I can define any method in my class, and it seems that we can just call that method directly on `unique_ptr` instance. Since C++ does not have dynamic method dispatch mechanism as Ruby does (AFAIK C++ method invocation is static and has to be defined, which makes sense since C++ is compiled directly into machine code), how is that even achievable?

Comment: Read about operator overloading (std::unique_ptr overloads the -> operator)

Comment: That's the magic of c++! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is achieved because the `operator->` can be overloaded to return another object or pointer. Which is then used with `operator->` recursively.

```
 class Dest
 {
     public:
        void test() {
            std::cout << "Test Called\n";
        }
 };
 class Forward
 {
     Dest d;
     public: 
         Dest* operator->() {
             return &d;
         }
 };
 int main()
 {
     Forward  f;
     f->test();    // operator-> on the object `f` returns a pointer to
                   // an object of type `Dest*`. Now apply re-apply the
                   // operator-> to the result.
                   //
                   // Since it is already a pointer this means access the
                   // member (which in this case is a method call).
 }
```

Comment: Since `operator->()` returns a pointer, it seems that we need to do `ptr->->method()` instead? Since the first `->` returns the pointer and the second one does the method invocation on pointer.

Comment: @OneZero. It would seem that way. But what it actually does is recursively apply `operator->` to the result.

Comment: @OneZero No, the operator-> obeys some special rules. It is applied recursively until the returned type is a pointer

Answer (score 3):

The most simple implementation of a smartpointer I can think of is this:

```
#include <iostream>     
struct A { 
    void moo(){std::cout << "MOO" << std::endl;}
};

template <typename T>
struct DumbPointer {
    T* t;
    DumbPointer(T* t) : t(t) {}
    ~DumbPointer(){delete t;}
    T* operator->(){return t;}
    void moo(){std::cout << "MOOMOO" << std::endl;}
};     

int main() {
    DumbPointer<A> f{new A()};
    f.moo();              // prints MOOMOO
    f->moo();             // prints MOO     
    return 0;
}
```

Overloading the `->` operator is done so that it looks like a pointer, while actually the `DumbPointer` itself is an object. For more details on overloading the operator see e.g. [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access). The relevant part is:

> If a user-defined operator-> is provided, the operator-> is called again on the value that it returns, recursively, until an operator-> is reached that returns a plain pointer. After that, built-in semantics are applied to that pointer.

PS: the example above is to be taken with a grain of salt. For example `DumbPointer<A> g = f;` will cause bad things to happen.

Comment: Why "DumbPointer<A> f = DumbPointer<A>(new A());" ? Isn't "DumbPointer<A> f (new A());" the same as the assignment semantics ?

Comment: @Talespin_Kit dont remember why I wrote it like it did. I changed it, because as it was before one could be mislead into thinking the default assignment operator would do the right thing, which is not the case. Note that there was no assigment, but only initialization

Answer (score 2):

I find James O. Coplien's explanation very clear and understandable in his book `Advanced C++`. Here is the explanation;

Overloaded `operator->` works different from other overloaded C++ operators. For all other operators, the body defining the operator's implementation has final control over the value returned from the operation. For `operator->` the return value is an intermediate result to which the base semantics of `->` are then applied, yielding a result. So,

```
class B {
    ...
};

class A {
public:
    B *operator->();
};

int main() {
    A a;
    ... a->b ...
}
```

means the following:

1. Invoke `A::operator->()` on object `a`;
2. Capture the return value from that invocation in a temporary, `x`, of type `B*`;
3. Evaluate `x->b`, yielding its result.

Here, `b` could be replaced by any member, data or function, of `class B`. If `class B` overloads `operator->` then the above three steps are applied again.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the class passed to unique_ptr can be arbitrary is that the class is a template parameter. You should read about templates, and how they work, but essentially there is a version of unique_ptr for every class you use it with, automatically, at compile time.

The way -> works is operator overloading. An instance of unique_ptr is not a pointer, rather it is an object that contains a pointer, and has operator overloads that allow you to use -> to access data in the object pointed to by that pointer. . accesses methods of the unique_ptr itself.